# Handle Paste event in DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataGridView with a column of the type DataGridViewTextBoxColumn. I want the user to be able to copy column data from Excel and paste it into the DataGridView. I'm capturing Ctrl+V in the key down event so I can parse the text and place it in the correct cells.

The problem I have is that after I assign values to the affected cells, the entire clipboard text is pasted in the active cell. For example, if `1\r\n2\r\n3` is pasted, I can place the 2 and 3 in their respective cells but `1\r\n2\r\n3` ends up in the active cell.

My code in the dgvCell_KeyDown event for reference

```
 private void dgvCell_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Control)
        {
            string text = Clipboard.GetText();
            string[] data = text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int col = dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int row = dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            if (data.Length <= dgv.Rows.Count - row)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    dgv.Rows[row + i].Cells[col].Value = data[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there an event that fires when a paste occurs or is there some way I can cancel the paste from the Key down event?

Right now, I have a hack in place where I'm setting a bool true in the key down event and then calling `e.Cancel = true;` in the key press event to stop the paste from happening; there has got to be a better way!